# Detecting Keyboard Events in PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt4, keyboard-events

I'm making a project with a few UIs, and I want to catch keyboard events and play some music in the last UI. I have shown the code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from pygame import mixer

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event handler')

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_W:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\qodud\Desktop\computingwork\bookA_Music\bookA_Music_W.mp3')
            mixer.music.stop()    

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

And I have code to define the UI class:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from pygame import mixer

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_bookA(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, bookA):
        bookA.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("bookA"))
        bookA.resize(400, 300)
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(bookA)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 260, 260))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget"))
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.backButton = QtGui.QPushButton(bookA)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 220, 80, 20))
        self.backButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("backButton"))
        self.pauseButton = QtGui.QPushButton(bookA)
        self.pauseButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 250, 80, 20))
        self.pauseButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pauseButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(bookA)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(bookA)

    def retranslateUi(self, bookA):
        bookA.setWindowTitle(_translate("bookA", "bookA", None))
        self.backButton.setText(_translate("bookA", "Back", None))
        self.pauseButton.setText(_translate("bookA", "Pause", None))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "저자 P.15 사랑하는 이들에게 - 정재형    \n"
"\n"
"욕심 P.66 1997 Spring - Yoshimata Ryo\n"
"\n"
"편지 P.79 River Flows In You - 이루마\n"
"\n"
"낭만 실조 P.80 Kiss the Rain - 이루마\n"
"\n"
"어떤 날 P.89 History -Yoshimata Ryo\n"
"\n"
"빈 소원 P.100 The Whole Nine Yards -Yoshimata Ryo", None))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

    def keyPressEvent(self,e):

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_W :
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\qodud\Desktop\computingwork\bookA_Music\bookA_Music_W.mp3')
            mixer.music.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    bookA = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_bookA()
    ui.setupUi(bookA)
    bookA.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the last module imports all of the UI and exchanges signals between the UIs:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature
from pygame import mixer
import sys

from first import Ui_First
from mymusicbook import Ui_mymusicBook
from booka import Ui_bookA
from bookb import Ui_bookB
from bookc import Ui_bookC

class First(QMainWindow,Ui_First,QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.popDialog1=mymusicBook()

    def on_startButton_clicked(self):
        self.popDialog1.show()

    def on_exitButton_clicked(self):
        self.close()

class mymusicBook(QMainWindow,Ui_mymusicBook):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.popDialog2=bookA()
        self.popDialog3=bookB()
        self.popDialog4=bookC()

    def on_book_A_Button_clicked(self):
        self.popDialog2.show()


    def on_book_B_Button_clicked(self):
        self.popDialog3.show()

    def on_book_C_Button_clicked(self):
        self.popDialog4.show()

class bookA(QMainWindow,Ui_bookA):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def on_backButton_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    def keyPressEvent(self,e):

        if self.e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_W :
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\qodud\Desktop\computingwork\bookA_Music\bookA_Music_W.mp3')
            mixer.music.stop()

class bookB(QMainWindow,Ui_bookB):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def on_backButon_clicked(self):
        self.close()

class bookC(QMainWindow,Ui_bookC):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def on_backButton_clicked(self):
        self.close()
```

I thought I had to handle events in last code, but it did not work. Where do I have to define the methods?

Comment: I had a similar application (music when a key is strocken). I would strongly advise you to go to pyqt5 as pyqt4 is not maintained anymore: http://julien.duponchelle.info/python/migration-from-pyqt4-to-pyqt5/
I had much less trouble with it. I'm not solving your problem, but perhaps you'd better spend energy solving it with pyqt5 than pyqt4...

Comment: @Wli. PyQt4 is still fully maintained, and there are no plans to stop supporting it.

Comment: Oh really? I might have read that from wrong sources... Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @ekhumoro. Thank you for revise. I should learn English more :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The widget that will handle the events is the current "focused" widget.
2. You can handle your KeyPressEvents in wherever you want.
3. You can also make something like [QKeyEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html).ignore inside the overwritten method then its father will take care of it, and so on.
4. A great option is also install a [EventFilter](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405544&seqNum=2) to the object you want to capture the events and handle it inside your filter manager.